# JDBC - reset connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am very new to Java.

I have Java class which implements the Database(Postgres) related functionality.

The problem is if Database stopped and then restart then My this class throws SQLException as connection got reset(database is up and running).

Is there any way that after Database restarted; my class automatically Connection to database and work as expected instead of throwing SQLException.

Is there any way with Properties as parameter to DriverManager.getConnection().

Thanks
MAP

Comment: catch the exception and try to reconnect

Comment: A database is Postgres. Is there anyway with Properties as the parameter to DriverManager.getConnection().

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch block to handle the SQLException. When you catch an SQLException, the program could wait a specified period of time and then try to reconnect, you could loop this as long as you want.

```
boolean connected = false;
// repeat until connected is true
while (!connected) {
    try {
       // put your connection code here
       connected == true;
    } catch (SQLException se) {
       // sleep for 10 seconds
       Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: A database is Postgres.

Is there anyway with Properties as the parameter to DriverManager.getConnection().

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, have you checked out the documentation online for your DB solution?